# 'powershell.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, django, powershell, terminal, pip

I am using Windows 10, and Windows Powershell as command terminal. I just started to learn Django framework and being trying to setup my env as 1st time practice.

This is my location: PS C:\Users\MyUsername\Desktop\cfeproj>

This was successful: python -m pipenv install

However, when I run : pipenv shell

PS C:\Users\LENOVO\desktop\proj> pipenv shell
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
'powershell.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Please help me ho to configure this problem. I'm basically very new and still learning.

Would be so appreciate if somebody can help me out here. =D

Comment: That's odd. What happens when you try to enable psv2: `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV2Root`? Can you run it after running this?

Comment: Hi @AbrahamZinala thank you for responding, how to do that? Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV2Root ? I'm really lost =(

Comment: Paste that into the console and hit enter.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala , i did, but it produce error.  >> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV2Root
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : The requested operation requires
elevation.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName
MicrosoftWindowsPo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOp
   tionalFeature], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindo
   wsOptionalFeatureCommand

Comment: Run a PowerShell console as an administrator and try again.